# Login failing with Spring security using BcryptEncoder

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

I have a problem when trying to login in my app. I just implemented BcryptEncoder for passwords, everything worked fine before. To test, I hashed a password online for my admin dummy, put it in database, and when I try to login it works.
Now, I have guest who can register in my web app, but after registration I can't login as a registered user even with right credentials. I do encode passwords before saving users to database, so it should works like for my admin dummy...
So, what am I missing? Thanks in advance for your help

**UPDATE** it seems like hash is being truncated in db, or not saved correctly, hence why hashed and raw password can't be possibly matching.
I tried matching the dummy password and the hashed one online and in fact they do not match. How do I solve?

**UPDATE2** db hash is matching hash provided by java using 
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder =new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    this.password = encoder.encode(password);
It seems that it hashes wrongly? Hashed results do never match when compairing them online at https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator

Here are my configuration files

**Application-context.xml**

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/customer/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login
        login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <security:logout
        logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                    authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, authority From authorities WHERE username = ?"
                                    users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE username = ?" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="12"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**Register Customer controller**

```
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;

@RequestMapping("/register")
public String registerCustomer(Model model){

    Customer customer=new Customer();

    BillingAddress billingAddress = new BillingAddress();
    ShippingAddress shippingAddress = new ShippingAddress();
    customer.setBillingAddress(billingAddress);
    customer.setShippingAddress(shippingAddress);

    model.addAttribute("customer", customer);

    return "registerCustomer";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerCustomerPost(@Valid@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, Model model, BindingResult result){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "registerCustomer";
    }

    List<Customer> customerList=customerService.getCustomerList();
    for(int i=0; i<customerList.size(); i++){
        if(customer.getCustomerEmail().equals(customerList.get(i).getCustomerEmail())){
            model.addAttribute("emailMsg", "Email already registered");

            return "registerCustomer";
        }
        if(customer.getUsername().equals(customerList.get(i).getUsername())){
            model.addAttribute("usernameMsg", "Username already registered");
            return "registerCustomer";
        }
    }

    customer.setPassword(customer.getPassword());
    customer.setEnabled(true);
    customerService.addCustomer(customer);

    return "registerCustomerSuccess";
}
}
```

In customer model I use

```
 public void setPassword(String password) {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder =new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    this.password = encoder.encode(password);
}
```

In customerDaoImpl to add customer I use

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void addCustomer(Customer customer){

    Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    customer.getBillingAddress().setCustomer(customer);
    customer.getShippingAddress().setCustomer(customer);

    session.saveOrUpdate(customer);
    session.saveOrUpdate(customer.getBillingAddress());
    session.saveOrUpdate(customer.getShippingAddress());

    Users newUser = new Users();

    newUser.setUsername(customer.getUsername());
    newUser.setPassword(customer.getPassword());
    newUser.setEnabled(true);
    newUser.setCustomerId(customer.getCustomerId());

    Authorities newAuthority=new Authorities();

    newAuthority.setUsername(customer.getUsername());
    newAuthority.setAuthority("ROLE_USER");
    newAuthority.setPassword(customer.getPassword());


    session.saveOrUpdate(newUser);
    session.saveOrUpdate(newAuthority);
```

In home page I have a login button, which prompts a form that checks credentials

**Controller part**

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestParam(value="error", required = false) String error, @RequestParam(value="logout",
    required = false) String logout, Model model){
    if(error!=null){
        model.addAttribute("error", "Invalid username and password");
    }
    if(logout!=null){
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Logged out succesfully");
    }

    System.out.println(">>>>> user ");
    return "login";
}
```

And the form

```
<div class="container-wrapper">
<div class="container">
    <div id="login-box">

        <h2>Login with Username and Password</h2>

        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>

        <form name="loginForm" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />" method="post">
            <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                <div class="error" style="color: #ff0000;">${error}</div>
            </c:if>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">User: </label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">

            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Users and Authorities model are quite simple, I omitted getters and setters

```
@Entity
@Table(name="authorities")
public class Authorities {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int authId;
private String username;
private String password;
private String authority;
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int userId;

private String username;
private String password;
private boolean enabled;


private int customerId;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

It appears that if you use tag "form:password"  in forms, it already auto-encodes the password for that input field. So if you hash it again it won't match the one typed by the user.
Classic "input type=""..." fields do not recieve encoding, you can use those if you want to make a change password page, and check the old password from db before validating password update.

I'll leave this here hoping it'll be helpful for other users in the future